# DC Coaxial Power Connector Rated for 20A

Tags: power-supply, current, wiring, ac-dc, coax

I have a 12V 20A power adapter seen here (https://www.ledwholesalers.com/v2/index.php?route=product/product&path=40_117&product_id=999). I would like to connect to this power supply, but my issue is that it ends with a coaxial connector and I can't find a compatible item. I've found something close to what I want (https://powerwerx.com/21mm-coaxial-socket-powerpole-adapter), but this is only 18awg whereas I'm looking for 12awg. Is there something better suited for the job or something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a barrel connector?

Comment: Aren’t barrel connectors and coaxial pretty much the same thing?

Comment: Not if you're searching for one but calling it the other

Comment: What is the device that you want to connect to the power source? Instead of looking for a adapter, it would be simpler (and far more reliable) if you cut out the plug of the power adapter, and solder the wires to a brand new plug that fits to the device that you want to power. It's simple like that. This procedure will not do any harm to your power source. Of course the warranty, but, do you really hope that something rough as a switched power source will really fail before the warranty time ends?